# Android architecture components with modules

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an app with a few modules. In my `base` module I am using

`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"`

and the app runs with no problem but when I switch to

`api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"`

android studio shows the error: `Default Activity not found`. Do I need to include the implementation in every module or is it possible to include the import in the base module?

Comment: Try with `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: Make sure you have specified the default activity in your AndroidManisfest.xml file. Within your default activity's xml<activity> section, there should be these tags:

            `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: Is this related? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79671572#comment3 hint: you may need a newer version of android studio